# how to use react router with parameter inside route like 'sitename.com/parameter/dashboard'

Tags: reactjs, parameters, react-router, navigation, router

I'm working on online shopping store based on react.
Suppose  i have `baseurl` like `onlineshopping.com` ,and i'm defining vendors dynamically.

Each vendor has it's own code

When  i wanna open site, i would like to pass a vendor code as parameter and after that, i wanna route to specific path.

Normally I'm using path like this to route to Dashboard component which is navigate to `onlineshopping.com/dashboard`:

```
<Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
```

I wanna use parameter between `onlineshopping.com` and `/dashboard` for navigating to `onlineshopping.com/vendorCode/dashboard`

I tried this, but not work

```
<Route exact path="/:vendorCode/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
```

here is my routing:

```
<BrowserRouter>
            <React.Suspense fallback={loadingComponent}>
                <Switch>
                    <LayoutRoute exact path="/:sid" component={OrderPage} />
                    <LayoutRoute exact path="/:sid/register" component={RegisterNewUser} />
                    <EmptyLayoutRoute exact path="/:sid/login" component={LoginOrRegister} />
                    <LayoutRoute exact path="/newvendor" component={RegisterNewVendor} />

                    <ProtectedRoute exact path="/:sid/profile" component={UserProfile} />
                    <ProtectedRoute exact path="/:sid/checkout" component={Checkout} />

                    <Route exact path="/:sid/d">
                        <Redirect to="/:sid/dashboard" />
                    </Route>

                    <DashboardLayoutRoute exact path="/:sid/dashboard" component={DashboardBranch} />
                    <DashboardLayoutRoute exact path="/:sid/dashboard/branch" component={DashboardBranch} />
                    <DashboardLayoutRoute exact path="/:sid/dashboard/product" component={DashboardProduct} />
                    <DashboardLayoutRoute exact path="/:sid/dashboard/region" component={Panel} />
                    <DashboardLayoutRoute exact path="/:sid/dashboard/scenario" component={DashboardScenario} />
                    <DashboardLayoutRoute exact path="/:sid/dashboard/message" component={DashboardMessage} />
                    <DashboardLayoutRoute exact path="/:sid/dashboard/orders" component={DashboardOrders} />
                    <DashboardLayoutRoute exact path="/:sid/dashboard/" component={UnAuthorizedAccess} />
                    <DashboardLayoutRoute exact path="/:sid/dashboard/report/sale" component={DashboardSaleReport} />
                    <DashboardLayoutRoute exact path="/:sid/dashboard/setting" component={DashboardSetting} />
                    <DashboardLayoutRoute exact path="/:sid/dashboard/users" component={DashboardUsers} />

                    <EmptyLayoutRoute exact path="/:sid/dashboard/login" component={DashboardLogin} />
                    <Route exact path="/:sid/p" component={DashboardProduct} />
                    <Route exact path="/unauthorized" component={UnAuthorizedAccess} />
                    <Route component={InvalidUrl} />
                </Switch>
            </React.Suspense>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: does `<Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />` work?

Comment: yes, it works and no problem

Comment: the best practice is to use the parameter at the end like `<Route exact path="/dashboard/:vendorCode" component={Dashboard} />`

Comment: i know, but in this scenario, i wanna to behave parameter as part of base url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the problem

My routing is correct

the problematic code is this:

```
const DashboardProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    return (
        < Route {...rest} render={props => {
            return rest.dashboardLoggedInUser ? (
                < Layout {...rest}>
                    <Component {...props} />
                </Layout >

            ) :
                (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: "/dashboard/login",
                            state: { from: props.location }
                        }}
                    />
                );
        }}
        />
    );
};
```

i forget to add parameter to DashboardProtectedRoute component

here is edited version which it works fine:

```
const DashboardProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    return (
        < Route {...rest} render={props => {
            return rest.dashboardLoggedInUser ? (
                < Layout {...rest}>
                    <Component {...props} />
                </Layout >

            ) :
                (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: `/${vendorCode}/dashboard/login,
                            state: { from: props.location }
                        }}
                    />
                );
        }}
        />
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe conflict with other route, can you share all your route ? or disable all other route and check again